# Generating and Displaying an Array Output Using HTML & JS

Tags: javascript, html

I've been attempting to create an array dynamically from user input and display the result in a specific format, like [100, 100, 200, 200, 300, 500, 900, 1500, 2400, 3800, 6100]. However, my current code isn't producing the desired output. Here's my HTML and JavaScript code:

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body style="text-align: center;">
    <h3 id="po">Input Array Elements</h3>
    <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="array[]" value="100" /><br>
        <input type="text" name="array[]" value="100" /><br>
        <input type="text" name="array[]" value="200" /><br>
        <button type="button" name="button" onclick="createArray()">
            Submit
        </button>
    </form>
    <br>
    <p id="par"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //var k = "Source Array is [";
        function createArray() {
            var k = "Source Array is [";
            var input = document.getElementsByName('array[]');
            let lastElement = input[input.length - 1].value;
            for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                var val = 0;
                if (i >= input.length) {
                    val = val * 2;
                    k += " " + val;
                } else {
                    val = input[i].value;
                    k += " " + val;
                }
                k += (i == 11) ? "]" : ",";
            }
            k += "]";

            document.getElementById('par').innerHTML = k;
            document.getElementById("po").innerHTML = "Output";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The current output is: [ 100, 100, 200, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,]

I'd appreciate any assistance or modifications to the code that would help generate the desired output array [100, 100, 200, 200, 300, 500, 900, 1500, 2400, 3800, 6100]. Thank you!

Comment: You've defined `val` inside the loop `var val =0;` which means that this: `val = val * 2;` will always set `val` to `0`.

Comment: yup, thats the question of my code exam

Comment: Can you describe the logic behind your desired output?